# Ruby on rails application in Windows Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, ssh, rubygems

Hi i have created a ubuntu virtual machine in windows azure for deploying my rails application..
   I have connected to my virtual machine through ssh and followed this procedure for deployment

```
<http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/install-rvm-ubuntu-1204-linux-for-ruby-193>
<http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/ruby/tutorials/web-app-with-linux-vm/>
```

My deployment was completed successfully. 
   While starting my server by running rails s in my application i am able to see my application up and running in browser. 
   My issue is the server is stopped for every 10 minutes and again i have to connect to my server through ssh and need to give rails s..
   i want a solution to run my application continously..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you haven't actually "deployed" anything. You just copied your rails app to a VM and ran `rails s`.

A production rails applications is not deployed in this fashion.

Consider using either nginx with unicorn or apache/nginx with passenger.

Comment: can u help me how to install apache/nginx